# Change of bases (arithmetic)

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

How can we check if a certain fraction in a certain base is infinite dizime.

If it is a infinite dizime how can we quickly find the representation of that fraction in that base.
The method I have to find its representation is quite slow in some cases and I would like to know if there is a faster method.

The method I have used consistes: Let's say I want to change to base 5. I check if the number ($z$) is between $a*5^n<z<(a-1)*5^n,(0 \le a<5)$ then I subtract $(a-1)*5^n$ and move to a lower base of $5$.

Comment: what does *dizime* mean and how can it be infinite?

Comment: @gt6989b "Dizime" seems to mean decimal (Portugese?). https://en.glosbe.com/pt/en/dizime  Though in OP's question, not necessarily with a base of 10. I suspect the question is asking how to tell if a rational number has a repeating "decimal" in some base; and if so, how to find that repeating decimal. That's my best guess. Apologies if I've misinterpreted. Feel free to correct.

Comment: You have $a$ and $(a-1)$ backwards in your chain of inequalities near the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fraction has an infinite repeat when the denominator (in lowest terms) has a prime factor that does not divide into the base.  In base $10$ the fractions that terminate are ones with denominators of the form $2^a5^b$.  If there is any other prime in the factorization of the denominator, the fraction will terminate.  If it terminates, it will have $\max(a,b)$ places because that is the smallest power of $10$ that $2^a5^b$ divides into.

Your approach to converting a whole number to another base works fine.  More commonly taught is to divide the number by $5$ and keep the remainder as the ones digit of the converted number.  Divide the quotient by $5$ and keep the remainder as the fives digit.  Keep going until you are done.  It is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion).